# Background to understand Gromov's green book

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, textbook-recommendation

I have a decent background in differential geometry. I have read John Lee's [introduction to smooth manifolds](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387954481) and doCarmo's Riemannian Geometry. I was trying to read Misha Gromov's [Metric structures for Riemannian and non Riemannian spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_Structures_for_Riemannian_and_Non-Riemannian_Spaces) but am finding it extremely difficult to follow. Any suggestions for books/papers as prerequisites ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slightly more advanced books on Riemannian geometry can help, in particular Petersen, and Gallot-Hulin-Lafontaine. Gromov draws a lot of his examples from Riemannian geometry !

Reading Burago-Burago-Ivanov "Introduction to metric geometry" is a also a good idea. It will give the necessary understanding of intrinsic metric spaces.

With this a good part of the book should be understandable.

Comment: I would say "some parts of the book" instead of "good part": Even if you have all the background in the world, reading Gromov's books usually not easy (but very rewarding!). Consider the story of Exercise number 1 from Gromov-Ballmann-Schroeder, which became an infamous open problem (and stayed so until very recently!).

Comment: @Misha: I hadn't heard that this exercise had been solved. Can you point me in the right direction? I spent some weeks as a grad student feeling quite dumb for being unable to solve it. ;)

Comment: @TomChurch - See here : http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.2198

Comment: Yes, a "good part" is probably really optimistic !

Comment: @ThomasRichard among Petersen and GHL, which would you recommend for self study ?